# Chart.js script does not update

Tags: javascript, html, charts

Im using Chart.js to to make the chart appear on the website, it doesn't update the information from the api. Maybe I have imported it incorrectly. I use the same script imports in index.html and in the js file of the script itself I don't understand what could be the problem here. https://codepen.io/jade1411/pen/LYrXPrX

```
function removeElementsByClass(className)
{
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    while(elements.length > 0)
    {
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }
}

function draw_graph(graph_data, header)
{
    var accepted = [], rejected = [], timestamps = [];

    if(typeof header === 'undefined') header = '';

//console.log(graph_data);

    for(var timestamp in graph_data)
    {
//      console.log("Data for " + timestamp + " a " + graph_data[timestamp]['a'] + " r " + graph_data[timestamp]['r']);
        accepted.push(Math.round(graph_data[timestamp]['a']));  // accepted_hashes
//      rejected.push(Math.round(graph_data[timestamp]['r']));  // rejected_hashes
        timestamps.push(timestamp);
    }
//  console.log("Data for " + timestamp + " a " + graph_data[timestamp]['a'] + " r " + graph_data[timestamp]['r']);
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Verdana';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle = 'normal';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#0B6FAB';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 11;
    Chart.defaults.global.legend = false;

    removeElementsByClass('chartjs-hidden-iframe');
// console.log(Canvas);
    new Chart(document.getElementById("global-speed-chart"), {
    type:'line',
    data:
    {
        labels: timestamps,
        datasets: [{
//              label: "accepted",
                data: accepted,
                borderColor: '#0B6FAB',
                backgroundColor: '#CBFFFF',
                borderWidth: 2,
                fill: false,
                pointRadius: 0
            }
//          ,{
////                label: "accepted",
//              data: rejected,
//              borderColor: "#3e95cd",
//              backgroundColor: "#000000",
//              borderWidth: 2,
//              fill: false
//          }
        ]
    },
    options:
    {
        title:
        {
            display: true,
            text: header,
//          fontStyle: 'bold',
//          fontColor: '#0B6FAB',
            fontSize: 16
        },

        legend:
        {
            labels:
            {
                fontColor: '#C0C0C0'
            }
        },

        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                position: 'right',
                gridLines: {
                    drawBorder: false
//,
//                  display:false
                },
//offset: true,
//              display: false,
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
//                  autoSkip: true,
//                  autoSkipPadding: 100,
                    maxTicksLimit: 3,
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    fontColor: '#C0C0C0',
                    fontSize: 9,
                    userCallback: function(label, index, labels)
                    {
                        if(label !== 0)
                        {
                            return label;
                        }
                    },
//                  labelOffset: 50
//                  max: 2000,
//                  min: 0
//                  stepSize: 100
//                  callback: function(value, index, values) {return '$' + value;}

                },
                scaleLabel: {
//                  display: false,
//                  labelString: '1k = 1000'
                },
                pointLabels:
                {
//                  display: false
                }
            }],

            xAxes: [{
//              display: false,
                gridLines: {
                    drawBorder: false,
                    display:false
//                  lineWidth: 0,
//                  zeroLineWidth: 0
                },

                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    autoSkip: true,
//                  autoSkipPadding: 0,
                    maxTicksLimit: 6,
//                  padding: 100,
                    fontColor: '#C0C0C0',
                    fontSize: 9,
                    maxRotation: 0,
                    minRotation: 0
                }
            }]
        }
    }});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`draw_graph` is not defined since the function definition is outside of the script tag in your HTML. If you copy and paste the code in your JS from codepen, and paste it into the script tag of your HTML, you should see it working.

Comment: Still doesn't work :(
Can you show how it should be?

Comment: https://codepen.io/jade1411/pen/qBKQmJJ what's wrong? I mean it still doesn't update, values are static.

Comment: I took a look at the link you posted, and the chart appears to be rendering. Is there another issue?

Comment: Yup, it static. What function should make it update?